# Python - convert hour from EDT/EST to UTC based on time of year

Tags: python, datetime, timezone-offset

Eastern Standard Time is -5 (to UTC)

Eastern Daylight Time is -4 (to UTC)

so why doesn't this work properly?

```
>>> import datetime, pytz

# 5 hour difference during Eastern Standard Time
>>> datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 25, 16, 26, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).hour
>>> 16

>>> datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 25, 16, 26, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).astimezone(pytz.utc).hour
>>> 21

# 4 hour difference during Eastern Daylight Time
>>> datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 25, 16, 26, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).hour
>>> 16

# So why does this not say 20?
>>> datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 25, 16, 26, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).astimezone(pytz.utc).hour
>>> 21
```

Comment: Note: I experience the same result when using `America/New_York`